# How to get a Python script running on GoDaddy hosting?

Tags: wordpress, python-3.x, rest

I'm pretty new to programming and I've made a small Python application with tkinter and would like to host it on my GoDaddy website.  I just can't seem to figure out how to connect the two.

Comment: Would you show us what you have tried? What GoDaddy package did you go for? Does it support Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have shared hosting account, Then you cannot use python scripts on go daddy. Because both cpanel and plesk shared hosting account does not support python. If you have deluxe or premium types hosting account then yes you can use python scripts. Even there also you can't use the modules which requires a compiler within virtual environment.

You have to enable SSH. For more you must contact their helping team..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run tkinter applications via a website.